# Emulator works totally fine, however APK on device does not work as expected

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am building an application for a school module, 
Whilst building this application I have been using the Emulator on 2.3.3 to test all changes/configuration.

However now that I have completed the application, I have built a debug APK and on some of my fragments when touching an image button it totally freezes and says "Has stopped" and gives me the option "open app again".

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Code extracts below that can be investigated:

**Mainactivity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.Viewimport android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.mercedes) {
        BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainLayout, blankFragment)
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.audi) {
        audi blankFragment = new audi();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainLayout, blankFragment)
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.bmw) {
        bmw blankFragment = new bmw();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainLayout, blankFragment)
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.empportal) {
        employeeportal blankFragment = new employeeportal();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainLayout, blankFragment)
                .commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.empportalv2) {
        employeeportalv2 blankFragment = new employeeportalv2();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.mainLayout, blankFragment)
                .commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void e63(View view) {

    e63room e63 = new e63room();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, e63)
            .commit();

}

public void gle63(View view) {

    gleroom gle63 = new gleroom();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, gle63)
            .commit();

}

public void c63(View view) {

    mercedesamgroom mercedesamgroom = new mercedesamgroom();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, mercedesamgroom)
            .commit();

}

public void rs3(View view) {

    rs3room rs3 = new rs3room();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, rs3)
            .commit();

}



public void rs4(View view) {

    rs4room rs4 = new rs4room();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, rs4)
            .commit();

}


public void rs5(View view) {

    rs5room rs5 = new rs5room();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, rs5)
            .commit();

}

public void m3(View view) {

    m3room m3 = new m3room();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, m3)
            .commit();
}

public void x6m (View view) {

    x6mroom x6m = new x6mroom();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, x6m)
            .commit();

}

public void m6(View view) {

    m6room m6 = new m6room();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainLayout, m6)
            .commit();

}
```

**androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have no idea what is causing this issue sadly.

device being used is samsung s8 & it has also been tested on samsung s6 and does not work.

I have tested both debug APK and release APK any help would be greatly appreciated this is a graded piece of work that is due for the 12th Jan

Comment: try deleting the build folder and disabling the instant run.

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't work:(.